# Dialogflow CX: Is it possible to verify the value of an intent param in the condition section of the page?

Tags: chatbot, dialogflow-cx

I would like to use **Conditions** to dispatch the conversation through different **Routes** depending on the intent entity that appeared in the last user's message:

[image: Route]

But it only enables me to use the condition **$intent.params.entityX != null**; when I try to extract the exact value of that entity like: **$intent.params.entityX = "some_value"** it does not match. I have also try $intent.params.entityX.**original** and $intent.params.entityX.**resolved**. It seems that the intent param values can apparently only be read in the Route response.

Answer (score 1):

If what you're looking for is to evaluate a parameter that may have been filled through entity detection, you may wanna check in session rather than the intent:
`$session.params.entityX`